# In Which situation we should use repeater control or Grid View Control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I manage a project and as you know asp.net has many types of data control, I am confused which control should be used in what condition. Which is better control in what situation. Should I still use repeater control because grid view is advance control.

Comment: @ayesha hassan... very good editing!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to understand the two is if you need a simple grid displayed use a gridview.
If you need to do additional formatting or display data from the database with additional graphics, labels, not in a grid type form than use a repeater. You can easily adjust the repeater to by as dynamic as you need it to be where as a grid view is a simple grid.

With a repeater you will click on the page SOURCE of the .Cs or .vb file and you will see 4 templates. Anything HTML you put in those templates will repeat with the data.

Answer (score 1):

A repeater allows you to have your items repeated both horizontally and vertically unlike a GridView which only by default repeat the items vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Around 2010 I ran into so much trouble with the GridView, I asked a (now former) Microsoft evangelist for advice. He strongly recommended not to use the GridView ever. Then I stopped and life got easier.